# Why are the contractors leaving lambs wool fibers in my floor finish?

Tags: flooring

Contractors continue to leave wool fibers in the finish. They rebuff the floor and add another poly finish but still leave wool fibers. What are they doing wrong? They seem to think this is ok and normal.

Comment: free insulation!

Answer (score 1):

They are using new clothes on final finishes.  New wool will shed maybe the first 10-20 times you use it and for finish coats I have only used older clothes or microfiber.  They could also be buffing a little too soon and this will definitely cause more wool to pull out.   I would hit the areas with wool with 320 grit sandpaper or just leave them in there and they will work their way out with more drying and usage.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice I've seen is to "de-fuzz" the wool applicators with duct tape or something similar before using them. Nothing will *completely* eliminate a few lost fibers, but this keeps them to a minimum.